# How to Reassign Consecutive Sequence/Incremental value (Counting numbers) on the list

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, sequence

I have the following list let's say list of products that have consecutive sequence:

```
new Product{Name = "iPhone 5S", Sequence = 1, Id = 100},
new Product{Name = "Galaxy S4", Sequence = 2, Id = 201},
new Product{Name = "Xbox One", Sequence = 3, Id = 209},
new Product{Name = "PS4", Sequence = 4, Id = 300}
```

There is a need that I want to change the sequence any of the product let's say for "iPhone 5S" I want to change the sequence from "1" to "3". Since sequence 3 is already taken what will happen it will reassign sequence number to other products and make sure no products have the same sequence values so the output will be:

```
Galaxy S4, Sequence = 1
Xbox One, Sequence = 2
iPhone 5S, Sequence = 3
PS4, Sequence = 4
```

As you can see on the desired output the sequences have been reassigned and put "iPhone 5S" to it's desired sequence. If the user will enter sequence greater than the highest sequence value, this product will be the last on the list and will also reassign sequences for products before it. Please help. Here's my sample code. I hope someone can help me. Currently my output is a mess it goes something like this:

**Mess Output**

[image]

**Here's my code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product{Name = "iPhone 5S", Sequence = 1, Id = 100},
                new Product{Name = "Galaxy S4", Sequence = 2, Id = 201},
                new Product{Name = "Xbox One", Sequence = 3, Id = 209},
                new Product{Name = "PS4", Sequence = 4, Id = 300}
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Original List");
            DisplayProduct(products);

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nEnter product id");
            var productId = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            var product = products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == productId);
            if (product == null) Console.WriteLine("Invalid product!");
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter new sequence for "+product.Name);
                var newSequence = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                product.Sequence = newSequence;

                var count = 1;
                foreach (var item in products)
                {
                    if (item.Id == product.Id)
                    {
                        count++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    item.Sequence = count;
                    count++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nModified product\n");
                DisplayProduct(products);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void DisplayProduct(IEnumerable<Product> products)
        {
            products = products.OrderBy(x => x.Sequence);
            foreach (var item in products)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sequence=" + item.Sequence + " Name=" + item.Name + " Id=" + item.Id);
            }

        }
    }
    public class Product
    {
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found simple and effective solution for this and I hope this will help anyone who needs something like this:

**Code snippet**

```
      var newSequence = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      if (newSequence <= products.Count&& newSequence>0)
         {
         products.Remove(product);
         products.Insert(newSequence-1,product);
         }
      else
         {
      products.Remove(product);
      products.Insert(newSequence <= 0 ? 0 : products.Count, product);
         }
      var count = 1;
      foreach (var item in products)
         {
         item.Sequence = count;
         count++;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you are unconditionally incrementing `count` here:

```
if (item.Id == product.Id)
{
    count++;
    continue;
}
```

This is incorrect when `count` is less than `newSequence`. This change should fix this problem:

```
if (count == newSequence)
{
    count++;
}
if (item.Id != product.Id)
{
    item.Sequence = count++;
}
```

The second problem is when `newSequence` is greater than the current max sequence, or when it is less than one. To make it work, you need to "cap" it at the current max sequence:

```
product.Sequence = Math.Max(1, Math.Min(newSequence, products.Max(p => p.Sequence)));
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/YQxOnx)

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me duplicate sequence. The output is: Galaxy S4, Sequence = 1;
Xbox One, Sequence = 2;
iPhone 5S, Sequence = 3;
PS4, Sequence = 3